Flush picture right of text inside minipage
I want to display a university logo flushed right from some text in a CV inside a minipage. I can't get to to work, neither with tables nor with wrapfigure. But I am a novice, I admit. How should this be done in LaTeX?
Now it looks like:

But I want it to look like:

\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=0.1cm,
    right=0.1cm,
    top=0.1cm,
    bottom=0.1cm
}

\definecolor{titleBack}{RGB}{100, 84, 82} % Wenge brown

\begin{document}
    
    \tcbset{colframe=gray!95!black,colback=titleBack,arc=0mm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
            %Picture
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{15cm}
            \begin{center}
                \Huge{\textcolor{white}{Name}} \\
                \vspace*{0.5cm}
                \Large{\textcolor{white}{Curriculum Vitae}}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    
    \tcbset{colframe=white,colback=white,arc=0mm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{8cm}
            \vspace*{-0.5cm}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to left by=0.6cm,colback=gray!15,colframe=white]
                \section*{Profile}
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{11cm}
            \vspace*{-0.5cm}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to right by=0.75cm,colframe=white,colback=white]
                \section*{Education}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item{
                        \begin{tabular}[!t]{l r}
                            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{University of X} \\ \emph{MSc Y} \\ \emph{April, 2024}\end{tabular} & \rule{4ex}{4ex}
                        \end{tabular}
                    
                        Some Text.
                    }
                    \item Another University
                \end{itemize}
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


Welcome! The tabularx package may help as it lets you specify the width of the tabular. Otherwise, LaTeX only makes it as wide as necessary to accommodate the contents. Or take the logo out and put it into a third minipage. [I'd probably think xcoffins if doing this, but they don't seem so popular. Make this kind of thing easier, though.]

I can't reproduce the output you show with the code you've posted, even after setting graphicx to use draft mode on account of the missing logo.jpg. Or is the background meant to half obscure Text? Is Education meant to be underneath Profile or to the right?

@cfr Thanks for your reply! I looked into tabularx and I couldn't get it to work either. I fixed the code, now it should work. I accidentally removed too much when I tried to make it as minimal as possible :)

I think I'd use tcolorbox's sidebyside option, at least in the first instance. Then you have additional alignment options minipage doesn't provide. Not quite as flexible as coffins, but more straightforward since you're already using tcolorbox.
For example,
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=0.1cm,
    right=0.1cm,
    top=0.1cm,
    bottom=0.1cm
}

\definecolor{titleBack}{RGB}{100, 84, 82} % Wenge brown

\begin{document}

\tcbset{colframe=gray!95!black,colback=titleBack,arc=0mm}%
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
    %Picture
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{15cm}
    \begin{center}
      \Huge{\textcolor{white}{Name}} \\
      \vspace*{0.5cm}
      \Large{\textcolor{white}{Curriculum Vitae}}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}


\tcbset{colframe=white,colback=white,arc=0mm}%
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{8cm}
    \vspace*{-0.5cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to left by=0.6cm,colback=gray!15,colframe=white]
      \section*{Profile}
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{11cm}
    \vspace*{-0.5cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to right by=0.75cm,colframe=white,colback=white,sidebyside,sidebyside align=center seam,righthand width=4ex+10pt]% adjust width as required for image and/or use width=\linewidth for \includegraphics
      \section*{Education}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item{
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{University of X} \\ \emph{MSc Y} \\ \emph{April, 2024}\end{tabular} 
          
          Some Text.
        }
        \item Another University
      \end{itemize}
      \tcblower
      \rule{4ex}{4ex}
      
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}

EDIT
Here's a version using tabularx which may work better for rows of universities.
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
% \usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=0.1cm,
    right=0.1cm,
    top=0.1cm,
    bottom=0.1cm
}

\definecolor{titleBack}{RGB}{100, 84, 82} % Wenge brown

\newlist{edulist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[edulist]{label=\textbullet,nosep}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\tcbset{colframe=gray!95!black,colback=titleBack,arc=0mm}%
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
    %Picture
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{15cm}
    \begin{center}
      \Huge{\textcolor{white}{Name}} \\
      \vspace*{0.5cm}
      \Large{\textcolor{white}{Curriculum Vitae}}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}


\tcbset{colframe=white,colback=white,arc=0mm}%
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{8cm}
    \vspace*{-0.5cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to left by=0.6cm,colback=gray!15,colframe=white]
      \section*{Profile}
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{11cm}
    \vspace*{-0.5cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to right by=0.75cm,colframe=white,colback=white]% adjust width as required for image and/or use width=\linewidth for \includegraphics
      \section*{Education}
      \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{Xm{5ex}}
        \begin{edulist}
          \item\textbf{University of X}
          
          \emph{MSc Y}
          
          \emph{April, 2024}
          
          Some Text.
        \end{edulist}
        &
        \rule{4ex}{4ex}
        \\
        \begin{edulist}
          \item \textbf{Another University}
          
          \emph{BPhil}
          
          \emph{July, 2024}
          
          Super quick!
        \end{edulist}
        &
        \includegraphics[width=4ex,height=4ex]{example-image-b}
        \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}

% \kant[1-5]
\end{document}


Could be further simplified in this case, but your real document may require e.g. the tabular, even though this doesn't.

Hey thanks for your reply. I don't think this works for me because it doesn't align the itemize dot well, plus I want logos to flush right for the other universities as well! I am surprised that I can't just right align a picture next to some text very easily. Shouldn't that be easy?

@Jori LaTeX wasn't designed for grid layouts. Columns and paragraphs, sure, but it's tricky wrapping text around images, for example. If you've looked at wrapfig's documentation, you'll get a sense of what I mean. But you can, of course, align things differently. However, a tabularx environment may make more sense if you want multiple rows.

@Jori See edit above. This demonstrates one way to use tabularx here.

Thank-you very much, it works! But most of it is magic to me. Learning LaTeX is so confusing and there do not seem to be any good books that teach you what you need to know to come up with this. You need to learn all the packages and how they conflict, it's confusing for new users (well, I am not new to LaTeX, but really understanding LaTeX is something else...) Any recommendations where to start really learning?

@Jori For packages, the LaTeX Companion edition 3 is probably the best resource. Be warned that it is not cheap. But I don't think most people know anything like all the packages. I don't think anybody does. It's more that you find packages to solve the problems you need to solve. Searching CTAN and texdoc the most promising results is surprisingly effective, actually.

I can propose an \itemlogo command.
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=0.1cm,
    right=0.1cm,
    top=0.1cm,
    bottom=0.1cm
}

\definecolor{titleBack}{RGB}{100, 84, 82} % Wenge brown

\newcommand{\itemlogo}[2][]{%
  \item\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\linewidth][r]{%
    \raisebox{\dimeval{\fontcharht\font`A-\height}}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
    }%
  }}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=gray!95!black,colback=titleBack,arc=0mm]
  \begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-1x1}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimeval{\textwidth-4.5cm}}
    \centering\color{white}
    \Huge Name\\
    \Large Curriculum Vitae
  \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}

\vspace{-0.5cm}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white,colback=white,arc=0mm]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{8cm}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to left by=0.6cm,colback=gray!15,colframe=white]
      \Large\bfseries Profile
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimeval{\textwidth-8cm}}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to right by=0.75cm,colframe=white,colback=white]
      {\Large\bfseries Education\par}
      \begin{itemize}
        \itemlogo[width=4ex]{example-image-1x1}
          \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
          \textbf{University of X} \\
          \emph{MSc Y} \\
          \emph{April, 2024}
          \end{tabular}

          Some Text.
        \item Another University
      \end{itemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


